# Get File Version from Application extension file

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

previously i used this code to check file version:

```
dim file_version as string    
file_version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(my file).FileVersion
```

the problem is when i check the file version with manual (properties in Explorer) i get the version is "1.8.12.0" but when i use this code i get "1.8L"
see my screenshot

[image]

any idea for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something seems to be incorrectly stored within `binkw32.dll` because `FileVersion` returns *Product Version* instead - it returns me `1.22W` because I have a little newer version. There is a workaround, build version info manually:

```
Dim myFileVersionInfo As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("...")
Dim version = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", myFileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart, 
                                               myFileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart, 
                                               myFileVersionInfo.FileBuildPart, 
                                               myFileVersionInfo.FilePrivatePart)
```

Given that, `version` contains `1.8.22.00` now (as I have this version).